# Newcommand with two optional arguments, one at the end

Tags: macros

I would like to define a new command with two optional arguments, one at the end. This works:

```
\newcommand{\matr}[3]{{}_{#1}\textbf{#2}_{#3}}
\matr{b}{M}{e}
```

But I would like to call it like this:

```
\matr[b]{M}[e]
```

leaving out the optional brackets, if I don't need them. Is it possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to use `\NewDocumentCommand`. The `o` argument specifier means an optional argument with no default value, which can be tested with `\IfValueTF` (in this case only the “true“ branch is necessary).

Note that `\textbf` is wrong in this context and you want `\mathbf`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

%\usepackage{xparse} % for LaTeX prior to the 2020-10-01 release

\NewDocumentCommand{\matr}{ o m o }
 {%
  \IfValueT{#1}{{}_{#1}\kern-\scriptspace}%
  \mathbf{#2}%
  \IfValueT{#3}{_{#3}}%
 }

\begin{document}

$\matr{M}$

$\matr[b]{M}$

$\matr{M}[e]$

$\matr[b]{M}[e]$

\end{document}
```

[image]